# How to pass the Querystring in pages?

Tags: pages

I can easily add menu in the admin panel menus.just select the pages and cretae menu. i need to set pages URL with querystring. is that possible?.

for example,

http://mysite.com/about for this url i need to set http://mysite.com/about?abt=12

how can i set this querystring value using menu?.

thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "custom link" for those pages where you need to add a querystring. Have you tried that? Best of luck!